# Why I fail to use properties from application.properties file in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Why I fail to use data from `application.properties` in the `PostDao` class?
Properties just not injected and DATABASE_URL and other variables are `null`.
`PostDao.java` is the class (src.main.java.site.model.PostDao) where I try to use properties.

```
@Component
public class PostDao
{
    @Value("${url}") public static String DATABASE_URL;
    @Value("${user}") public static String USER;
    @Value("${password}") public static String PASSWORD;
}
```

Here is my `application.peoprerties` file which stays in the resources directory

```
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/news
user=postgres
password=123
```

Here is my config file (src.main.java.site.NewsSiteApplication)

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class NewsSiteApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(NewsSiteApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Static variables are initialized before any other instance variables including Spring framework's.  @Value is injected via Spring. Also, possibly a duplicated question.

Comment: A remark: In general, it is expected that only constants (aka `static final` fields that are unmodifiable) are written in `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE`.

Comment: @memoricab that isn't the problem in this case. Spring could set the value of static fields (since they are not `final`), if Spring were able identify that those fields should be injected. So really the root cause is that spring does not discover static fields as injection targets.

Comment: @Turing85 it can be overwritten, at execution time Value annotation will work after initialising the static fields. Don't you think it is relative?

Comment: @memoricab As I said: setting the value of the field is not the issue. Discovery is the issue. Spring does not analyze each and every field of each class for annotations. Spring only analyzes instance-fields of managed bean classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can do the following, the setter method will handle for the injection:

```
@Component
public class PostDao
{
    public static String DATABASE_URL;


    @Value("${url}")
    public void setUrlStatic(String name){
        PostDao.DATABASE_URL = name;
    }

    // And others..
}
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that this approach requires that the surrounding class is a managed bean (I know that the class presented in the question is a bean, it should nevertheless be mentioned).

Comment: @Turing85 right, edited.

Answer (score 4):

You can't inject in a static variable. You need a Spring-managed Bean for that. Try the following:

```java
@Component
public class PostDao {
    @Value("${url}") public String databaseUrl;
    @Value("${user}") public String user;
    @Value("${password}") public String password;
}
```

As pointed out by @Turing85 (thanks for the hint ;) ), only constants should be written in `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE`, hence I changed the variables name.

---

My suggestions in regards to your code that is currently based on static methods, when it shouldn't as explained in my comment.

```java
@Component
public class PostDao implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
    @Value("${url}")
    private String databaseUrl;

    @Value("${user}")
    private String user;

    @Value("${password}")
    private String password;

    private Connection connection;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl, user, password);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Post> getAllPosts()
    {
        ArrayList<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();

        String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id;";
        try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement(); 
             ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sqlQuery)
        )
        {
            while (resultSet.next())
            {
                int id = resultSet.getInt("id");
                String header = resultSet.getString("header");
                String image_filename = resultSet.getString("image_filename");
                String text = resultSet.getString("text");
                java.util.Date creationDate = resultSet.getDate("creation_date");

                posts.add(new Post(id, header, image_filename, text, creationDate));
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return posts;
    }

    public void addPost(String header, String imageFileName, String text, Date creationDate)
    {
        String sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO news VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

        try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery))
        {
            preparedStatement.setString(1, header);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, imageFileName);
            preparedStatement.setString(3, text);
            preparedStatement.setDate(4, new java.sql.Date(creationDate.getTime()));

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void deletePost(int postId)
    {
        String sqlQuery = "DELETE FROM news WHERE id = ?;";

        try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery))
        {
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, postId);

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void updateHeader(String header, int postId)
    {
        String sqlQuery = "UPDATE news SET header = ? WHERE id = ?;";

        try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery))
        {
            preparedStatement.setString(1, header);
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, postId);

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void updateText(String text, int postId)
    {
        String sqlQuery = "UPDATE news SET text = ? WHERE id = ?;";

        try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery))
        {
            preparedStatement.setString(1, text);
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, postId);

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void updateImageName(String imageFilename, int postId)
    {
        String sqlQuery = "UPDATE news SET image_filename = ? WHERE id = ?;";

        try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery))
        {
            preparedStatement.setString(1, imageFilename);
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, postId);

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void updateDate(java.util.Date date, int postId)
    {
        String sqlQuery = "UPDATE news SET creation_date = ? WHERE id = ?;";

        try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery))
        {
            preparedStatement.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, postId);

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you need to inject the `PostDao` bean in your `PostsController` as follows:

```java
@Controller
public class PostsController
{

    private PostDao postDao;

    public PostsController(PostDao postDao) {  // This instructs Spring to inject a PostDao bean
        this.postDao = postDao;
    }

    @GetMapping("/posts")
    public String showPosts(HttpServletRequest request, Model model, @RequestParam(value = "modify", required = false) boolean modify)
    {
        if (modify && request.isUserInRole("ADMIN"))
        {
            model.addAttribute("modify", true);
        }
        
        // truncate text to 150 characters and add " ..."
        ArrayList<Post> posts = postDao.getAllPosts();
        for (Post post : posts)
        {
            String text = post.getText();
            if (text.length() > 150)
            {
                text = text.substring(0, 151);
                text = text.trim().concat(" ...");
            }
            post.setText(text);
        }
        
        model.addAttribute("posts", posts);
        return "posts";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/posts/{id}")
    public String showPostById(Model model, @PathVariable("id") int id)
    {
        model.addAttribute("post", postDao.getAllPosts().get(id - 1));
        return "post";
    }
}
```

Comment: nothing is changed, error message is the same

Comment: Have you turned the static variables into instance variables? What is the error message?

Comment: Can you also add the code in which you try to use the variables and how that code is called? Thanks!

Comment: `Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, USER, PASSWORD);` this statement throws an error because DATABASE_URL is null, so it't hasn't been injected

Comment: but I used @codemonkey solution and it works

Comment: Sure, but where is this code? And how do you get an instance of `PostDao`?

Comment: All PostDao methods is static so I don't need to instantiate is

Comment: Then that is the reason why my solution does not work because they are now instance variables instead of static (as they should). Still, it does not seem that you have the right design in your classes, but that is another topic. Great that you have solved it, nevertheless.

Comment: https://github.com/Denys-coder/News-site/commits/master it's the whole project, last commit

Comment: I am not saying it doesn't work, because it obviously does. I am just saying the whole design does not seem right to me. You have `PostDao` as a Spring-managed bean but you basically do not use it as such, since you then call all those static methods that should be instance methods instead. Each call to `PostDao` means that you will create a new connection to the database when this should be done only once because this is an operation with a cost in terms of performance. I will add my suggestions to my answer ;)

Comment: Done, please check it ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a great job, I will surely check it. Project design is bad, I know, but I started learning Spring-Boot 3-4 weeks ago (I don't know Spring) and 1 week ago I started making this project, so main goal is just to consolidate knowledge.

Comment: You are welcome! In that case, I suggest you this awesome book --> https://www.manning.com/books/spring-in-action-sixth-edition so that you can learn more about Spring ;)